# How to use Payment gateway in my iPhone app

Tags: ios, payment-gateway

I am developing an iOS App. In that I want to sell books to the User. In simple words, I want Payment Gateway Integration in my iOS App. My Research shows that we have option to use Apple Payment Gateway API but for every transaction they will charge 30% for them.

**Is there any other way to implement this and Apple will approve ?**

Comment: Physical books or e-books?

Comment: So finally which SDK  you used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apple payment gateway/API is for in-app purchases (of virtual goods, apps, etc). For physical items/items which have value outside the app, you're free to use whatever payment gateway/API you wish, such as PayPal (cool new SDK for US-based payers), Square (not available in Asia), or any local online payment gateway that you have available depending on your region.

Comment: Thanks for your reply govindani,But is there any link to get PayPal SDK am not able to find it.

Comment: Posted comment on the wrong answer lol: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/ios-integration-guide/

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a web interface where you can implement payment gateway. and generate a token which user can use for purchase the book.

But still you need to provide In-App purchase (Apple provided) in case of e-book and in case of physical book i don't think you need in-App purchase you can use above way or any other way which you think better.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ishu am trying to use Paypal sdk which they provide for easy payment.

Comment: Start here: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/ios-integration-guide/ - note that this is only for US-based customers. If non-US, you'll need the legacy SDK.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an SDK to accept physical payments within your app, then check out CardFlight (https://getcardflight.com). They provide the hardware and SDK so that you can accept a physical card swipe and handle the payment processing, all within your own app.

Full disclosure: I am currently working on this. We realized the opportunity for an open payment platform that processes credit card swipes within your own app when we realized there wasn't anything like this on the market.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of payment/charging Apple payment gateway/API is for in-app purchases (of virtual goods etc.). For physical items which have value outside the app, I guess you're free to use whatever payment gateway/API you wish, such as PayPal (new SDK for US-based payers) who introduced a new mobile SDK that allows iOS app developers to integrate PayPal checkout and mobile credit card payment mechanisms directly into their apps.

This means that you are not looking at just having a PayPal button inside the app, where users are redirected to Safari on iPhone to complete their transactions, but with this new SDK users can pay without ever leaving the app or any local online payment gateway that you have available depending on respective region.